# flask-mysqldb support for Python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, flask-mysql

Simply I'm trying to connect Flask with MySQL DB

- I have Python 3.6  version
  and

  `$pip3 --version`

o/p : `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)`

While installing **flask-mysqldb** extension getting *error mysql config* not found.
As mentioned in site http://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ there's support only Python 2.7, 3.4 and 3.5 what about 3.6 ? is there any
good *alternative* to flask-mysqldb ?

Comment: It's quite unusual that python3.5 source code would fail in python3.6 interpreter. Can you provide exact error message you're receiving and verify if installing it on Python 3.5 works, when it breaks on Python 3.6? Environment issue is much more likely than source code incompatibility.

Comment: Nope even its not installing with Python3.5

Comment: Nope even its not installing with Python3.5 and 2.7 here's complete error log [link]( http://pastebin.com/SSkB3q6B) , and [link]  (http://pastebin.com/bpX2J85C) error log with 3.6 here [link](http://pastebin.com/EBKJi2BG )